# Java : Debugger is not stopping inside Third Party API class files

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am using a Third Party API ( From a Private Organisation ) .when i am using that , 
An Application specific error is coming  that is(  Data is not Screenable )so i thought to debug their API .

For this , from their jar i have taken all the source files (Java Files ) with the help of jd-GuI Decompiler , and produced those  source Files to that particular  Jar File from Eclipse , but when i tried to put a Break Poing inside that particular class file in Eclipse , the Debugger is not stopping there .

Could anybody please let me know , how to resolve this ??

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

Remove all break points and just leave only one break point before the code you want to debug. Eclipse may not catch the break point if the api runs in another thread.
Do you have source code available to you?

Comment: Please tell me what do you mean by "Have you add the source codes into your class path? if not try add them on your class path" ??

Answer (score 1):

"Regular" breakpoints are based on the source line number, so if the source you have is off by even one line, breakpoints will not work as expected. The line you *think* you're putting a breakpoint on, may be a blank line or in a branch that doesn't get executed in the actual code.

Every time I got this problem, it turned out that the binary and source jars of the third party library were of slightly different versions.

The solution is to somehow get the original sources that were used to compile the class files you have.

For a quick fix, you can also try putting a **method breakpoint**, which is based on the method signature rather than the line number. Note that these can significantly slow down the debugger however.

Comment: Ya , i have done that (that is putting a Break point inside the Method signature itself under the Generated Source from JD-GUI De compiler ) but still it doesn't stop there . And i don't have the Original Source code .

Comment: Just to confirm: are you sure that it's actually a method breakpoint and not a line breakpoint on the method declaration line? Method breakpoints have a slightly different icon, as you can see here: http://www.eclipse-tips.com/tips/29-types-of-breakpoints-in-eclipse#MethodBreakpoint

If it's in fact a method breakpoint and it's not stopping, then that method isn't getting called. You can try breaking at a higher level caller (such as your test harness) and stepping into methods, and see if you can figure out which method is getting called.